# What is the best way to select rows with two conditions of the same column using GROUP BY in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, group-by, having

```
TABLE
id   |   result
==================
1    |   SUCCESS
2    |   FAIL
2    |   SUCCESS
3    |   FAIL
3    |   FAIL
3    |   SUCCESS
4    |   FAIL
5    |   FAIL
5    |   FAIL
```

I want to select those ids that have at least one 'FAIL' and no 'SUCCESS'. In this example, only id = 4 and id = 5 should be selected.

This query doesn't seem to work since HAVING is not aggregating over anything:

SELECT id, result FROM table WHERE result = 'FAIL' GROUP BY id HAVING result != 'SUCCESS'

Does anyone know how this can be done without using IN clauses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    id
    , sum(if(result='SUCCESS', 1, 0)) as cnt_succ
    , sum(if(result='FAIL', 1, 0))    as cnt_fail
FROM 
    table 
GROUP BY
    id
HAVING
    cnt_fail>0 and cnt_succ=0
```